# webview not work on all domains

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to implement a webview in my app(android Studio). This was very easy. Unfortunately, not all domains are loaded:

```
    String url="https://www.secretdomain.ch/"; //sorry i must remove the domain
    webView=(WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

This will not work, no page loaded.

When i try https://www.google.ch/ or https://stackoverflow.com/ everything works.

What could be the reason for this? I do not think it's the website itself, because on ios (Xamarin) the webview worked without any problems. Is there a workaround?

Comment: have you tried  to open your url in mobile default  web browser?

Comment: @  Ajeet yadav: yes, this work fine..
I have also testet with errormethods: onReceivedHttpError and onReceivedError i dont'n have any errors :-(

Comment: How do you mean or not loaded? Can you show what need to be loaded with a screenshot or something like that?

Comment: I checked the website with a ssl validator. There is a problem here. I think that this may be the cause

Comment: I have found a Solution:

`@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ff00ff">
<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webView1"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

class:

```
{
    {
        wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wb.loadUrl("https://www.dkh.ch/");
        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }
}
```

Comment: I have now taken your complete code to test. Unfortunately does not work